# replicate php readline() array in browser

Tags: php, arrays, browser, terminal

simple php code that works well in terminal:

```
<?php

$a = array();

for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){

    $b = readline('time: ');

    $c = readline('money: ');

    $d = array('time'=>$b, 'money'=>$c);

    array_push($a, $d);

    }

print_r($a);
```

this pushes the values of multiple entries into an array, creating an array of arrays. however, readline() does not work in the browser. i know i can use javascript easily enough but am trying to replicate this simple action using only php and html. and i really like the way readline() works. i have tried variations on the following but am left scratching my head:

```
<form method="POST">
    
    <?php 

      for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){ 

    ?>

        <input name = 'time'>
    
        <input name = 'money'>
    
    <?php 
    
        } 
    
    ?>
       
    <input type="submit">
        
</form>

<?php

print_r($_POST['time']);
```

was hoping `print_r($_POST['input name'])` would return an array, but instead only gives the last input entry. is there a straight forward way to do this with php, or do i HAVE to use a client-side script like javascript?

Comment: You can use [`str_repeat`](https://onecompiler.com/php/3yksd6b5v) for elegancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `[]` to input names:

```
<form method="POST">
    
    <?php 

      for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){ 

    ?>

        <input name = 'time[]'>
    
        <input name = 'money[]'>
    
    <?php 
    
        } 
    
    ?>
       
    <input type="submit">
        
</form>

<?php

print_r($_POST['time']);
```

Comment: When you see a new basic question asked in 2022, you can be sure that Stack Overflow already has the question answered several times. [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)